# Error handling using ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js

Im trying to perform error handling on the client side. below is my code:

```
function($, _, Backbone, mainAccountCollection,accounttmpl){
    var mainAccountDetails = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(){
                accountids = this.options.id 
        },
        render: function(id){   

            var self = this;
            var accountdetails = new mainAccountCollection([],{ id: id });
            accountdetails.fetch({
                success: function(accountview){ 
                    var data = accountview.toJSON();    
                    var accountData = data[0].data
                    var template = $("#main-account-details").html(_.template(accounttmpl, {accountData:accountData})); 
                },

                 error: function(xhr){
                    if (xhr.status === 404){
                     alert('Your status of request is' + xhr.status);
                    }
                }
            });

        }, 

});
```

On alert i do not get any message or alert. the response i get from the server os the xml format.

[image]

Im not sure how can i get the code or the status in order to alert something when there is either a 404-Not found or 401- Unauthorized.

Any ideas.please
Thanks!

Comment: do I correctly understand that you receive provided response but with status code 200?

Comment: no, i dont get a 200. i get a 404 record not found. however im trying to alert that 404 status code in the message, and im not able to..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thin you use wrong signature for callback function. From documentation:

> The options hash takes success and error callbacks which will both be passed `(collection, response, options)` as arguments

Try to change this:
`error: function(xhr){`
to something like this:
`error: function(col, xhr){`